# Mixing quotes in PHP

Tags: php, mysql

I have this script that gets my info from the DB

```
$result = mysqli_query($con,"SELECT * FROM <table> WHERE id = 3");

while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result))
  {
  echo '<p>'.$row['name'].'</p>' . " " .'<p>' . $row['description'] . '</p>' . " " . '<p>' . $row['price'] . '</p>';
  echo "<br>";
  echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/'.$row['profile_pic'].'" alt="profilepic" />';
  echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/'.$row['pic1'].'" alt="pic1" />';
      ^^^                                                *********
      Here is the problem because I should have sigle quote at the beginning and at the end, but I still have it above ***.And I use double quotes for the src on the <img> so those are taken too.
  echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/'.$row['pic2'].'" alt="pic2" />';
  echo '<img src="http://www.example.com/images/'.$row['pic3'].'" alt="pic3" />';
  }
```

If I do it like I intended, I would need another set of quoter( maybe triple :]] )..How can I do it the right way?

Comment: What's wrong with what you have now? (Only thing I see is `'</p>." ".'<p>'` can become `'</p> <p>'` with no issue)

Comment: A heredoc will be much easier to read.

Comment: To do it the right way would be to separate the view PHP functionality.

Answer (score 3):

The source code you have looks good. You can use `\` character immediately ahead of a single or double quote to `escape`, like so:

`$variable = "my quote's are \"like this\" ";`

`// output: my quote's are "like this"`

Likewise:

`$variable = 'this is "how my quotes" don\'t look';`

`// output: this is "how my quotes" don't look`

Comment: But there's nothing in his code that he'd have to escape, unless the database fields have quotes in them.

Comment: Yeah, I don't understand the question either. His original code looks good. I suppose he wants to include additional quotes somewhere?

Comment: I see. You can safely wrap single quotes inside of doubles, and vice versa. They do not close one another, only a matching single to single (or double to double) will terminate.

Comment: Ohhh...Good thing to know...Thanks @SetSailMedia

Answer (score 2):

You can use the [`HEREDOC`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.syntax.heredoc) syntax as follows. Variables can be used inline without any `{}` brackets. Arrays must be wrapped in `{}`. Both types of variables can be embedded in-line.

```
while($row = mysqli_fetch_array($result)){

// "EOH" can be any string of your choosing, but you must close with it
$output = <<<EOH;
<p>{$row['name']}</p> <p>{$row['description']}</p> <p>{$row['price']}</p>
<br>
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/{$row['profile_pic']}" alt="profilepic" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/{$row['pic1']}" alt="pic1" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/{$row['pic2']}" alt="pic2" />
<img src="http://www.example.com/images/{$row['pic3']}" alt="pic3" />
EOH; // from above; MUST be aligned all the way left (don't intent or tab)

echo $output;
}
```

Comment: Can EOH have no connection at all with the script?

Comment: Yes, it can be any string of text. But, it must be the same at the start `= <<<X;` and at the termination `X;`

Answer (score 2):

Rasmus Lerdorf answered you since his introduction of PHP by prefixing the variables name with  $
Simply you have to do something like the following:

**edited**

```
//Place any string in double quote
echo "<p> {$row['name']} </p> <p> {$row['description']} </p> <p> {$row['price']} </p>";
```

The following is quote from an [interview with Rasmus](http://www.phpclasses.org/blog/post/226-4-Reasons-Why-All-PHP-Frameworks-Suck.html)

> #### $ Dollar Sign in PHP variables
>
> When asked about why variables start with the $ sign, he explained
> that was meant to be able to insert variables inside literal string
> values, so a mark would need to be used to distinguish what is a
> variable from the rest of the string.
>
> Since he wanted the variables to look the same inside and outside a
> string, he has chosen the $ sign to start variables, inspired in the
> solution that Perl also adopted.

Comment: You may need `"...{$row['name']}..."` for this to work on complex variables.

Comment: @tadman I think that the only complex contest that may need curly braces is SQL query string. However, your notice is very useful. Thank you.

Comment: This is not accurate. Placing array variables inside double quotes, without `{}` brackets, will throw a syntax error `T_ENCAPSED_AND_WHITESPACE`.

Comment: @SetSailMedia The answer has been corrected. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to call `htmlspecialchars()` around each item in the `$row` hash, i.e. `htmlspecialchars($row['profile_pic'])`.

mysqli_fetch_assoc() will be slightly more memory-efficient than mysqli_fetch_array().

Comment: Interesting - why is `fetch_assoc()` more efficient than `fetch_array()`? I would think it's the other way around, but I'm not familiar with raw data transfer format

Comment: fetch_array() returns both a numeric array and an associative array. fetch_assoc() returns only an associative array.