# Double and single quotations PHP

Tags: php

When I put single quotations and I inspect. The output is always a double and single quotation. echo "<form action='includes/departure.inc.php' method='POST' onsubmit='if (!confirm('departure') {return false};'>";
The output is: https://i.stack.imgur.com/2bLvd.png

Comment: You're not creating a valid string. `onsubmit='if (!confirm('departure') {return false};'` the inner quotes here must be escaped.

Comment: And how would you escape?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Mixing quotes in PHP](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21585777/mixing-quotes-in-php)

Comment: You are looking at the code in the  development console, that code is often transformed by the browser. You should instead look at the source code from the dom. As an example, this SO page source would be accessible from `view-source:https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65373432/double-and-single-quotations-php` in chrome. (Winodws/Linux shortcut would be CTRL+U)